# Can you use single characters in the Toy Box, even if you don't have the correct play set?

Tags: disney-infinity

If I purchase a single character when I don't own the play set that character belongs to (for example, if I purchase Francesco but not the Cars 2 play set), can I use that character in the Toy Box?

Or are you forced to always purchase the Play Set first, before any of the single characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any character you purchase is playable in the Toy Box regardless of whether you own their specific playset or not.